# Show different pages based on user - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building a web app IMDB's like. Each (logged) user views the same exact homepage, but they can flag/unflag every movie they want to save them in a "seen list". I've done that but I've noticed that every user logged can view the other user's flagged movies. Of course this is a problem, so I'd like to build a page relative to each user, so that everyone would have different "seen films" page based on the movies flagged as seen.
The main idea behind this, is that whenever a user adds a movie to the database, he can flag it as seen with a simple models.BooleanField in the model of the film. I have then another model "Seen" where there are all the movies flagged.

> models.py

```
class Films(models.Model):
    ...
    seen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
class Seen(models.Model):
    ...
```

> views.py

```
    films = Films.objects.all()
    for film in films:
    flag = 0
    seen_films = Seen.objects.all()
    for _ in seen_films:
        if film.name == _.name:
            flag = 1
            break
    if not flag and film.seen:
        act_seen = Seen(image=film.image, name=film.name, description=film.description)
        act_seen.save()
```

I need to add that for the user, I use the default class provided by django:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

I get that the error is everyone can flag/unflag a movie and so everyone can see other user's movies but I have no idea how to fix that. Also I think the code in views.py is very raw but it was more a test than the final product. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [extend the default User class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) (check the docs, there is several ways to do this and the one I use may not be the best one for you) and use a many-to-many to save all the movies that the user has seen:

```py
# models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    films_seen = models.ManyToManyField(Films, related_name='seen_by')
```

Then you could use a `ListAPIView` and override the `get_queryset()` method:

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class FilmsSeenList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.profile.films_seen.all()
```

Note that you must be sure that each user has a profile associated (with a signal for example, [docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/)), else `get_queryset()` would raise a `Profile.DoesNotExist`:

```py
# handlers.py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from accounts.models import Profile  # Define where your Profile model is here

User = get_user_model()


@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="create_profile")
def post_save_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    # Making sure that a profile is assigned for new users
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

You could also implement a view returning all the films and a flag to know if the user saw the film:

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class AllFilmsList(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = FilmsSeenFlagSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Films.objects.all()


# serializers.py
class FilmsSeenFlagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    seen = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_seen(self, instance):
        return instance.seen_by.filter(pk=self.context['request'].user.pk).exists()

    class Meta:
        model = Films
        fields = [..., 'seen']
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll surely try this possible solution. I've also thought about implementing a models.OneToOneField but I have 2 main doubts: would it work? Do i have to implement it inside the FIlm class or User class?

Comment: @EddyIT You could not use a OneToOne instead of the many-to-many, as it would mean that a Film could only be linked to one user and vice-versa.

Comment: Got it thx. When you say "Note that you must be sure that each user has a profile associated (with a signal for example)", in my views.py every method has the decorator @login_required, so that i cannot access any page if i'm not logged in, could that already be a certainty that i'm a user with a profile associated?

Comment: @EddyIT Not really, this will just ensure that `request.user` won't be None. By default, creating a User instance will not automatically create a Profile instance, which causes the exception when accessing user.profile. I've added some code about the signal in my answer if it can help.